# вопрос из задачника js не понятен

Tags: javascript

Счастливое число-это то число, в результате последовательного сложения квадратов цифр которой, при какой-то итерации получается 1.

На пример число 23 счастливое число, потому-что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, в результате трех шагов мы получили 1, что подтверждает, что 23 это счастливое число. Необходимо разработать функцию, которая получает число и возвращает true, если данное число счастливая и false в противном случае.

Заметим, что для определения счастливых чисел на каждом шагу получается какое-то
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] число (в нашем примере 13,10,1). если число не счастливая, то в [image: введите сюда описание изображения] числах встречаются повторяющиеся цифры.

задачу нужно решить под 4 варианта:

1. на входе:23 на выходе: true
2. на входе:44 на выходе: true
3. на входе:10 на выходе: true
4. на входе:28 на выходе: true

ещё есть подсказка:

при поиске счастливых чисел на каждом шагу получается определенное 'y' число, цифры которой нужно попытаться сложить. Если число не счастливая, то число 'y' может повториться в каком-то i шаге. Следовательно, если число 'y' встречается более одного раза внутри цикла, необходимо вернуть false

Comment: Для начала покажите, что сами пытались сделать. Или Вы просто кинули задачу, чтобы Вам всё решили?

Comment: что именно непонятно?

Comment: @Denis640Kb,@Grundy мне не понятен сам вопрос и способ её решения, затрудняюсь представить, структуру самого кода, и как получилось что в результате трёх шагов у нас как-то вышел 1

Comment: у тебя же картинка в вопросе, на которой показаны эти три шага: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9CST.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function solution(x) {
    if (x === 4) return false;
    const u = x.toString().split('').reduce(((ac,cv) => ac + Math.pow(cv,2)), 0);
    if (u === 1) return true;
    else return solution(u);
}
console.log(solution(10))
console.log(solution(23))
console.log(solution(44))
console.log(solution(28))
```

Answer (score 3):

Берешь число (например 44). Разделяешь на 2 числа (4 и 4). Возводишь оба в степерь `4*4 = 16 + 4 * 4 = 32`. Теперь число 32. Берешь это число и разделяешь на 2 отдельных числа (3 и 2) возводишь 3 в степень, возводишь 2 в степень. Складываешь. `3*3 + 2*2 = 13` теперь у тебя число 13. Разделяешь на 2 отдельных числа 1 и 3. `1*1 + 3*3 = 10`, теперь число 10. `1*1 = 1, 0*0 = 0. 1+0=1`

Теперь надо сделать всё то же самое, но на JS + обратить внимание на подсказку и подумать как защититься от бесконечного цикла.